# Accessing bean from Jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets, javabeans

I searched on this forum but haven't got appropriate solution. And if by mistake this one is duplicate then sorry.

Coming to problem...
I'm setting the values from one of my HTML using servlet like this
code for index.html

```
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="user">
What's your name? <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="username" SIZE=20>`
```

code for servlet

```
package test;
  ......
UserBean ub = new UserBean();
String name = request.getParameter("username");
ub.setFirstName(name);
request.setAttribute("user",ub);
RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/getJsp.jsp");
rd.forward(request,response);
```

both servlet and bean are placed in package called test.

code for UserBean:

```
private String firstName;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    System.out.println(firstName);
}
```

From the bean I'm able to print the proper value for name on server console.
After setting the values from servlet i'm trying to acceess bean values from the JSP called getJsp.jsp

getJsp.jsp

```
<table>
   <jsp:useBean id="user" type="test.UserBean" class="test.UserBean" scope="request" >   
    <tr>
       <td>  Id : </td>
       <td> <jsp:getProperty name="user" property="firstName"/></td>
   </tr>
   </jsp:useBean>
</table>
```

When accessing the bean properties from JSP i'm getting the following error:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /getJsp.jsp (line: 10, column: 1) The value for the useBean class attribute UserBean is invalid.

I'm not able to understand the problem in the code for this error. 
Help me out please.

Thank you.

Comment: @JB thank you for the help. I already tried that too. Just now I tried same example in netbeans with both approaches but either i'm getting "null" or nothing at all

Comment: -1 for not posting a new question (or at least editing the existing one with follow up info) for a new problem quite unrelated to the original one.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal I updated in comments under your answers everything if you had checked it. Anyways thanks for letting me know that I have to update the question rather than commenting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the error message, it seems like the actual code of the JSP uses `class="UserBean"` and not `class="test.UserBean"`.

But more importantly, the reason why you found nothing when searching for an answer is that you're implementing your JSP like if nothing had changed in the JSP area for more than 10 years. `jsp:useBean` and other `jsp:xxx` tags are completely obsolete. Learn how to use the JSP EL and the JSTL, and replace the code of the JSP by

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>  Id : </td>
       <td><c:out value="${user.firstName}"/></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

This will have the additional advantage of escaping the HTML special characters in the user name.

Comment: thank you for the help. I already tried that too. Just now I tried same example in netbeans with both approaches but either i'm getting "null" or nothing at all. AAnd same code I pasted through notepad and run the application manually thorugh TOmcat and this time I got the error saying : javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'firstName' not readable on type test.UserBean.

Comment: I did as told by you using netbeans the value is not getting outputted.

At same time i tried same thing wthout Netbeans this time I'm getting same error from the previous comment:
    javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'firstName' not readable on type test.UserBean

Comment: Are you sure your getter is public? Are you sure it's spelled getFirstName()? Are you sure the class is well compiled and present under WEB-INF/classes?

Comment: I forgot about the public access specifer for the class specifying that the error has gone but still output is not printed on screen(JSP page).
the methods are public..
getFirstName() is also correctly spelled..
class is compiled and placed under WEB-INF/classes/test as per the package I specified earlier

Comment: Check the page source in your browser. Make sure it doesn't contain `<c:out ...>`. If it does, it means you forgot to properly declare the core taglib at the top of the JSP page. Also consider just putting ${user.firstName} in the page. Be aware that it won't html-escape the first name though.

Comment: i haven't placed the required jstl jar file in lib folder. Please tell me one more thing is jstl 1.2 latest available? Thank you again for helping